# Optimize my function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to improve the function, as I'm new to jquery, I need a better way to remove the elements using the below function. Any type of adjustments, opinions, improvements will be helpful. Below is the div when I enter a duplicate number an error message is added when user removes the number i need to remove the elements for which the below function is used.

```js
function removeElements(input){
    if($(input).next().next().is('label.errorLabel')){
        $(input).next().remove();
        $(input).next().remove();
    }else if($(input).next().is('a.addUserNo') && $(input).next().next().next().is('label.errorLabel')){
        $(input).next().next().remove();
        $(input).next().next().remove();
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="usrNoDiv" style="padding-left: 50%;">
    <input type="text" id="8855885555" name="usrNo1" value="8855885555"><br> 
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="8855588888" name="usrNo2" value="8855588888"><br> 
    <br><input type="text" name="usrNo3">
    <a href="#" class="addUserNo"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size: 20px;padding-left: 5px;"></i></a><br>
    <label class="errorLabel" style="color:red">User already Logged</label><br><br>
    <button type="button" id="submitData">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your HTML and explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: better for codereviews stack exchange

Comment: As @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs stated. Optimization questions refer to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Start with caching `$(input).next()` in a variable i.e. `var next = $(input).next();`

Comment: What the first three people said.  But as long as we're here:  depending on lots of relative traversals like you're doing with all those `next()`s is generally not a good idea. It's really fragile: some day you rearrange the design a tiny bit and all your scripts break.  If you need to work with a specific element, put a classname on that element so you can refer to it directly.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBeck

Comment: Thanks @Satpal, it really got out of my mind that I could use caching, that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of wrong things here.

**First of all** you have plenty `br` elements, so `$(input).next().next()` will always be a `br` and not `label`

**Secondly** you should **not** use jQuery `$()` call more than it is necessary. A better approach would be saving it to a variable (e.g. `var $input = $(input);`) and then instead of using `$(input)` just use this variable (e.g. `$input`).

**Last but not least** instead of using `.next().next()` you can do `.nextAll().eq(1)`

`.nextAll()` returns all next elements and `.eq(1)` gets the second element (0 is the first one)

**Your solution**

```js
$("input").on('focus', function() {
  removeElements(this);
});

function removeElements(input) {
  var $input = $(input);
  if ($input.next().next().is('label.errorLabel')) {
    $input.next().remove();
    $input.next().remove();
  } else if ($input.next().is('a.addUserNo') && $input.next().next().next().is('label.errorLabel')) {
    $input.next().next().remove();
    $input.next().next().remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="usrNoDiv" style="padding-left: 50%;">
  <input type="text" id="8855885555" name="usrNo1" value="8855885555">
  <input type="text" id="8855588888" name="usrNo2" value="8855588888">
  <input type="text" name="usrNo3">
  <a href="#" class="addUserNo"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size: 20px;padding-left: 5px;"></i></a>
  <label class="errorLabel" style="color:red">User already Logged</label>
  <button type="button" id="submitData">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**Here is my idea on how you can do it**

```js
$("input").on('focus', function() {
  removeElements(this);
});

function removeElements(input) {
  var $input = $(input);
  if ($input.nextAll().eq(1).is('label.errorLabel')) {
    $input.next().remove();
    $input.next().remove();
  } else if ($input.nextAll().eq(1).is('a.addUserNo') && $input.nextAll().eq(2).is('label.errorLabel')) {
    $input.nextAll().eq(1).remove();
    $input.nextAll().eq(1).remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="usrNoDiv" style="padding-left: 50%;">
  <input type="text" id="8855885555" name="usrNo1" value="8855885555">
  <input type="text" id="8855588888" name="usrNo2" value="8855588888">
  <input type="text" name="usrNo3">
  <a href="#" class="addUserNo">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="font-size: 20px;padding-left: 5px;"></i>
  </a>
  <label class="errorLabel" style="color:red">User already Logged</label>
  <button type="button" id="submitData">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Krzysztof Janiszewski, that helped a lot. I'll be trying the same. Thanks for your help.